# delete [ and ] in df.Comment in pandas datastream

Tags: pandas

i want to delete certain strings in a pandas datastream.
These are for example [ and ] .
How can i do this?

I already tried with the function:

```
#dataframe2['Comment'] = dataframe2.Comment.str.replace('[','')
```

But what i get is that the whole Comment gets replaced by NaN.

I want that only the content afterwards and before is there like:

[https://www.hallo.com]

Should be: https://www.hallo.com

Comment: can you post how you data looks like? I'm thinking it's likelly you have `list`s and no strings in your dataframe, in which case you won't fix it by using `str.replace`.

Comment: the data looks like this:  Comment 
1 [https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/ww/de... 
2 [https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/de/de... 
3 [4.3.10.9, https://support.industry.siemens.co... 
4 [https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/ww/de... 
5 []